# ImageMagick composite resizes image before composing

Tags: resize, imagemagick, composite, watermark

I'm using ImageMagick's composite command to compose one smaller image over larger one. The resulting image should be of size of the background image (the larger one). Additionally I want the smaller one to be always of the same size.

Currently I have such a simple invocation:

```
composite -gravity SouthWest watermark.png photo.jpg photo.jpg
```

The problem is that I get different sizes of watermark for different photos and I don't know how to set it to be fixed size. I tried -resize, -geometry and -size options but all of them change size of resulting image and not the watermark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and tried all sorts of different options with the composite command to try to get it to work.  Eventually I had to switch to using the convert command and was able to get it to resize with gravity using:

```
convert photo.jpg -gravity SouthWest -draw "image Over 0,0,200,200 watermark.png" photo.jpg
```

The numeric parameters for -draw are left,top,width,height.  See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#draw.  So this solution no longer uses the composite command but hopefully gives you what you want.

Answer (score 4):

**Hurraaay!**

I have found the answer from a little note in the ImageMagick manual that says `-resize '1x1<'` is essentially a no-op (and SHORT-CIRCUIT) for the resize operation.

So, if I have a 1200x1200 image.jpg and I overlay it with a 600x600 copyright.png, using this command:

```
composite -dissolve 50% -gravity center image.jpg copyright.png result.jpg
```

my image gets resized to 600x600 as per the copyright.png.

However, if I do the following:

```
composite -resize '1x1<' -dissolve 50% -gravity center image.jpg copyright.png result.jpg
```

my output image retains its orginal size of 1200x1200.